# Filtering/reducing df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my DataFrame with State and County as index, sorted by county population.

[image: DataFrame]

I'm trying to figure out how to return ONLY the three most populous counties in each state.  Been trying for hours.  Couldn't find any ways to do this.

Comment: Could you please edit some sample data into your question for a bit more context?

Comment: OK.  Sorry first time

Comment: Are you looking at df.groupby('State')['County'].nlargest(3)?

Comment: @A-Za-z  yes that's it!  Thank you!!

Comment: @MattR, done :)

Answer (score 1):

As requested, posting this as an answer,

```
new_df = df.groupby('State')['County'].nlargest(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of your dataframe names and column names but try something like this:

```
print(DATEFRAME_NAME_HERE['2010 Pop.'].nlargest(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the framework,but maybe a simplistic approach helps.You said that the values are indexed and sorted. Is there a reason you can't find the last index and add those values to a list for showing? Something like

```
temp_store = []
max_index = x
for i in range(3):
  temp_store.append(DATASTRUCTURE[(max_index - i)])
```